# AWS S3 sync buckets in two different accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to run `aws s3 sync s3://bucket-in-account-1111 s3://bucket-in-account-2222`

We do not want to use bucket policies, rather we want to use cross-account IAM roles.

We own both accounts, and access them using AWS SSO. I have admin access to both accounts via an assumed SSO role.

I have attempted to follow the guidance in the section [Cross-Account IAM Roles](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3). I am getting the permissions error `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied`.

Goal is to copy objects from `bucket-in-account-1111` to `bucket-in-account-2222`

I have created roles in accounts 1111, and 2222 called `role-1111` and `role-2222`:

- `role-1111`

  - Permissions Policy: Allow, Action `"sts:AssumeRole"`, Resource `"arn:aws:iam::2222:role/role-2222`"
- `role-2222`

  - Permissions Policy: Allow, Action `"s3:*"`, Resource `"aws:arn:s3:::bucket-in-account-2222", "aws:arn:s3:::bucket-in-account-2222/*"`
  - Trust Policy: Allow, Action: `"sts:AssumeRole"`, Principal: `"AWS: arn:aws:iam::1111:role/role-1111"`

With this configuration, logged in to account 1111 as my normal role,

- These work:

  - list the contents with `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-in-account-1111`
  - assume role to role-2222 `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::2222:role/role-2222 --role-session-name me@example.com`
  - from that role list the bucket, e.g. `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-in-account-2222`
- But these fail:

  - from 1111 normal role, I can't list bucket-in-account-2222
  - from 1111 assumed role-2222, I can't list bucket-in-account-1111
  - in either case `aws s3 sync` fails

Is there a way that a role in account 1111 can have access to buckets in both accounts at once such that a command like `aws s3 sync` or a copy between accounts will succeed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't work that way.

You need **one set of credentials** that can read from Account 1 **and** write to Account 2.

As per the *IAM policies and resource-based bucket policies* section of the article you linked, you will need BOTH:

- An IAM Role
- A Bucket Policy

It is not possible to **read from Account 1** and **write to Account 2** using only IAM policies because you will be using only one IAM Role at a time.

The concept of a "cross-account IAM Role" simply grants you access to assume an IAM Role in another account. It does not give access to buckets in multiple accounts unless you use it together with a Bucket Policy.

Therefore your choices are:

- Use a Bucket Policy together with the IAM Role, *OR*
- Download the files to your computer using one Account, then assume the IAM Role in the other Account and Upload the files using that IAM Role (without using `aws s3 sync`)

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, thank you. The role + bucket policy approach is the only solution because the bucket policy on the foreign account effectively expands the scope of the local account's permissions such that a single account can access resources of both at once. I guess I can use conditions to lock the bucket down.

Comment: Yes. You only need to grant access to the `Principal` of the IAM Role.

Comment: @TomHarrison see also [How Amazon S3 Authorizes a Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-s3-evaluates-access-control.html).  If a role in account B needs to access a bucket in account A, then *both* the bucket policy in A and a policy attached to the role in B need to grant the access to the bucket in account A -- the bucket policy allows the bucket to be accessed by the foreign user, and the user (role) policy allows the user to access the foreign bucket, both of which are denied by default.  Non-cross-account 
bucket access doesn't require both.